# Categorizing data based on the data's signature

Tags: database, hash, indexing, categorization

Let us say I have some large collection of rows of data, where each element in the row is a (key, value) pair:

```
1)    [(bird, "eagle"), (fish, "cod"),      ... , (soda, "coke")]
2)    [(bird, "lark"),  (fish, "bass"),     ...,  (soda, "pepsi")]
n)    ....
n+1)  [(bird, "robin"), (fish, "flounder"), ...,  (soda, "fanta")]
```

I would like the ability to run some computation that would allow me to determine for a new row, what is the row that is "most similar" to this row?

The most direct way I could think of finding the "most similar" row for any particular row is to directly compare said row against all other rows. This is obviously computationally very expensive.

I am looking for a solution of the following form.

- A function that can take a row, and generate some derivative integer for that row. This returned integer would be a sort of "signature" of the row. The important property of this signature is that if two rows are very "similar" they would generate very close integers, if rows are very "different", they would generate distant integers. Obviously, if they are identical rows they would generate the same signature.
- I could then takes these generated signatures, with the index of the row they point to, and sort them all by their signatures. This data structure I would keep so that I can do fast lookups. Call it database B.
- When I have a new row, I wish to know which existent row in database B is most similar, I would:

  1. Generate a signature for the new row
  2. Binary search through the sorted list of (signature,index) in database B for the closet match
  3. Return the closest matching (could be a perfect match) row in database B.

I know their is a lot of hand waving in this question. My problem is that I do not actually know what the function would be that would generate this signature. I see Levenshtein distances, but those represent the transformation cost, not so much the signature. I see that I could try lossy compressions, two things might be "bucketable" as they compress to the same thing. I am looking for other ideas on how to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: This is my original answer, which we will call Case 1, where there is no *precedence* to the keys**

You cannot do it as a sorted integer because that is one dimensional and your data is multi-dimensional.  So "nearness" in that sense cannot be established on a line.

Your example shows bird, fish and soda for all 3 lines.  Are the keys fixed and known?  If they are not, then your first step is to hash the keys of a row to establish rows that have the same keys.

For the values, consider this as a poor man's Saturday Night similarity trick.  Hash the values, any two rows that match on that hash are an exact match and represent the same "spot", zero distance.

If N is the number of key/value pairs:

The closest non-exact "nearness" would mean matching N-1 out of N values.  So you generate N more hashes, each one dropping out one of the values.  Any two rows that match on those hashes have N-1 out of N values in common.

The next closest non-exact "nearness" would mean matching N-2 out of N values.  So you generate more than N more hashes (I can't figure the binary this late), this time each hash leaves out a combination of two values.  Any two rows that match on those hashes have N-2 out of N values in common.

So you can see where this is going.  At the logical extreme you end up with 2^N hashes, not very savory, but I'm assuming you would not go that far because you reach a point where too few matching values would be considered to "far" to be worth considering.

**EDIT:** To see how we cannot escape dimensionality, consider just two keys, with values 1-9.  Plot all possible values on a graph.  We see see that {1,1} is close to {2,2}, but also that {5,6} is close to {6,7}.  So we get a brainstorm, we say, Aha! I'll calculate each point's distance from the origin using Pythagorean theorem!  This will make both {1,1} and {2,2} easy to detect.  But then the two points {1,10} and {10,1} will get the same number, even though they are as far apart as they can be on the graph.  So we say, ok, I need to add the *angle* for each.  Two points at the same distance are distinguished by their angle, two points at the same angle are distinguished by their distance.  But of course now we've plotted them on two dimensions.

**EDIT:  Case 2 would be when there is *precedence* to the keys, when key 1 is more significant than key 2, which is more significant than key 3, etc.  In this case, if the allowed values were A-Z, you would string the values together as if they were digits to get a sortable value.  ABC  is very close to ABD, but very far from BBD.**

Comment: This is something that people keep saying, and I sort of get it, but intuitively I just don't grasp it. I mean yes, the data is multi-dimensional. But lets say I limit each value to less than 50 characters, so that there is a finite number of possible permutations: can I not then map a finit number of permutations onto a (conceptually) infinite number of integers? Apologies if it is kind of a dumb questions.

Comment: Oh, and to answer your first question, yes, I meant to indicate that the keys are given, known, and specifically ordered. I should have been more clear.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. I think I get it a little more clearly. I was focusing too much on whether a finite number of things could be mapped, and not enough on whether that mapping would have any meaning.

Answer (score 1):

If you had a lot of data, and wanted to do this hardcore, I would suggest a statistical method like [PLSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_latent_semantic_analysis) or [PSVM](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/dmi/svm/psvm/), which can extract identifying topics from text and identify documents with similar topic probabilities.

A simpler, but less accurate way of doing it is using [Soundex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php), which is available for many languages.  You can store the soundex (which will be a short string, not an integer I'm afraid), and look for exact matches to the soundex, which should point to similar rows.

I think it's unrealistic to expect a function to turn a series of strings into an integer such that integers near each other map to similar strings.  The closest you might come is doing a checksum on each individual tuple, and comparing the checksums for the new row to the checksums of existing rows, but I'm guessing you're trying to come up with a single number you can index on.

Comment: Hah, yeah, the first two were way to complicated to bother with. The Soundex thing sounds (lame pun) interesting, but I don't think is precisely what I am looking for.


Maybe it is unrealistic, but it seems like it **could** exist. Why can a hash function not be made that has the property that similar strings will probabilistically hash to similar hashes.